# typo3 bootstrap accordion - collapse the initial element

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, accordion, typo3-7.6.x

This is related to Typo3 with the bootstrap theme only please.

I'd like to have ALL elements of the accordion **closed** at page startup. Currently the top element **[is open like here](http://trustix.soficas.com/content-elements/bootstrap-accordion/)**

In do understand that it's only related to the `in` in the `class` of this statement

```
<div id="panel-425-0" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
```

but changing this in the source would have side effects to other locations which I'like to avoid.

So I'm looking for a solution to do the closure with CSS or javascript.

Any guidance welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here try this

So basically you get element by its Id and re-set its class attribute without the 'in' class.

```
<script>
    document.getElementById('panel-425-0').setAttribute('class','panel-collapse collapse');
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for completenes, my own reminder and to whom it might help the full TS to be put into the setup section of a template

```
# get some javascript into 
# for hiding the first accordion element

page.jsFooterInline.20 = TEXT
page.jsFooterInline.20.value = document.getElementById('accordion-....').setAttribute('class','panel-collapse collapse');
```